# How to match in range color?

Tags: c++, opencv

I try to extract text by detect the color from purple to red. this's the HSV image https://ibb.co/6JKKY68. But it only return black.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

int main()
{
    cv::Mat tempt;
    cv::Mat img = cv::imread("image.png");

    cv::cvtColor(img, tempt, cv::COLOR_BGR2HSV);

    cv::inRange(tempt, cv::Scalar(274, 50, 60), cv::Scalar(360, 255, 255), img);

    cv::imshow("image", img);
    cv::imshow("tempt", tempt);

    cv::waitKey(0);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hello, I might be wrong but I'm pretty sure that in OpenCV, Hue has values from 0 to 180, Saturation and Value from 0 to 255. Thus, OpenCV uses HSV ranges between (0-180, 0-255, 0-255)

Comment: @AchilleG ow, i use gimp application to get HSV range, in gimp the range is 360, 100, 100. i read somewhere, 100 equal to 255. okay,  i will test the hue divide by 2

Comment: use this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSKh8.png

Comment: yes, the H value should be divided by 2

Comment: @AchilleG i'm using `cv::inRange(tempt, cv::Scalar(143, 50, 150), cv::Scalar(180, 255, 255)`. it only detect first word. "Favor".  180 hue is red with sue, vue max. whats wrong again?